# MMQGIS Geocode Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field

Tags: qgis, geocoding, error, qgis-2.10, mmqgis

I am running QGIS 2.10, and I'm trying to geocode a list of addresses using a .csv file in the MMQGIS geocoder. I just installed the plugin. When inputting my file, I immediately get a Python Error:

*An error has occured while executing Python code:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/derekkaden/.qgis2/python/plugins/mmqgis/mmqgis_dialogs.py", line 1143, in browse_infile_dialog
    header = mmqgis_read_csv_header(self.iface, newname)
  File "/Users/derekkaden/.qgis2/python/plugins/mmqgis/mmqgis_dialogs.py", line 2605, in mmqgis_read_csv_header
    header = reader.next()
Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?*

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else searching in the future the error message in question:

> Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?

That error seems to happen on mac computers. The script expects a universal / windows line-end character. Probably could be fixed by the plugin developer, but in the mean time there's some fix suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315635/csv-new-line-character-seen-in-unquoted-field-error

to quote:

> For Mac OS X, save your CSV file in "Windows Comma Separated (.csv)" format.